# How to pass value to a modal in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using a modal from bootstrap mdb for angular as a dialog to delete a record. Can you please show me how to pass the data to the modal. I took the modal code from "https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/modals/basic/". This is an MDB Bootstrap for angular.

This is how my code to delete with confirm:

```
<div
  mdbModal
  #basicModal="mdbModal"
  class="modal fade"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myBasicModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">
          Are you sure you want to delete this record?
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          mdbBtn
          color="secondary"
          class="waves-light"
          aria-label="Close"
          (click)="basicModal.hide()"
          mdbWavesEffect
        >
          No
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          mdbBtn
          color="danger"
          class="relative waves-light"
          mdbWavesEffect
          (click)="onRemove(log)"
        >
          Yes, remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<mdb-card>
    <mdb-card-body>
      <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Remove</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            *ngFor="let log of logs; let i = index"
            [class]="i % 2 == 0 ? 'table-info' : ''"
          >
            <td>
              <span class="table-remove">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  mdbBtn
                  color="danger"
                  rounded="true"
                  size="sm"
                  class="my-0"
                  (click)="basicModal.show()"
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </mdb-card-body>
</mdb-card>
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is literally an example on how to inject data into the modal on the page you linked: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/modals/basic/#inject-data

Comment: Yes I saw it but the "MDBBootstrapModulesPro" is for the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the model in ts file component:

Change your html to:

```
          (click)="openModal()"
```

add to your component this:

```
  openModal() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalComponent, { this.modalOptions });
  }
```

this.modalOptions is your data

Comment: Where did the modalRef come from Sir?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 you need import { MDBModalRef } from 'ng-uikit-pro-standard'; And add to constructor:   constructor(public modalRef: MDBModalRef) {}